# Selenium does not detect page load (Ruby)

Tags: selenium, rspec

I am currently using 
- firefox 13
- selenium-server-standalone-2.23.1.jar
- selenium-client (1.2.18)
- rspec 1.2.8

Selenium stops here even if page has fully loaded

08:49:43.888 INFO - Command request: waitForPageToLoad[300000, ] on session 2718493e6d4640eea76d6cb3ab1a6fc3

```
require 'rubygems'
require "selenium/client"
require "selenium/rspec/spec_helper"

describe "Google Search" do
    attr_reader :selenium_driver
    alias :page :selenium_driver

  before(:all) do
      @selenium_driver = Selenium::Client::Driver.new \
          :host => "localhost",
          :port => 4444,
          :browser => "*firefox",
          :url => "http://www.google.com",
          :timeout_in_second => 10
  end

  before(:each) do
    selenium_driver.start_new_browser_session
  end

  # The system capture need to happen BEFORE closing the Selenium session
  append_after(:each) do
    @selenium_driver.close_current_browser_session
  end

  it "can find Selenium" do
    page.open "/"
    page.title.should eql("Google")
    page.type "q", "Selenium seleniumhq"
    page.click "btnG", :wait_for => :page
    page.value("q").should eql("Selenium seleniumhq")
    page.text?("seleniumhq.org").should be_true
    page.title.should eql("Selenium seleniumhq - Google Search")
    page.text?("seleniumhq.org").should be_true
    page.element?("link=Cached").should be_true
  end

end
```

Comment: Are there any other errors coming through from your script execution?

Answer (score 0):

I wonder if the google page is using AJAX which is confusing the page load event.

When I went to http://google.com I noticed that submitting the search only added #q=selenium to the url.

This could likely be confusing selenium. Maybe instead of wait for pageload you can wait for page element

Some search element xpath (for example) /html/body/div[1]/div[3]/div[3]/div[6]/div[2]/div[3]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/ol/div[2]/li[1]/div (ugly I know)